# How do I make the player in my game intercept falling objects on canvas?

Tags: javascript

I am making a game in which the player intercepts falling objects, but I don't know how to do that. I already have the code that creates the player which is movable by using the mouse, and I have randomly generated falling objects. 
Here is the code:

```js
(() => {
    let canvas = document.getElementById("game");
    let game = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let lastTimestamp = 0;
    let score = document.getElementById("playerScore");

    const FRAME_RATE = 60;
    const FRAME_DURATION = 1000 / FRAME_RATE;

    let fallers = [];

    const DEFAULT_DESCENT = 0.0003; // This is per millisecond.
    let Faller = function (x, y, width, height, dx = 0, dy = 0, ax = 0, ay = DEFAULT_DESCENT) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        // Velocity.
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;

        // Acceleration.
        this.ax = ax;
        this.ay = ay;
    };

    Faller.prototype.draw = function () {
        game.fillStyle = "blue";
        game.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    };

    Faller.prototype.move = function (millisecondsElapsed) {
        this.x += this.dx * millisecondsElapsed;
        this.y += this.dy * millisecondsElapsed;

        this.dx += this.ax * millisecondsElapsed;
        this.dy += this.ay * millisecondsElapsed;
    };

    const DEFAULT_PLAYER_WIDTH = 45;
    const DEFAULT_PLAYER_HEIGHT = 15;
    const DEFAULT_PLAYER_Y = canvas.height - DEFAULT_PLAYER_HEIGHT;
    let Player = function (x, y = DEFAULT_PLAYER_Y, width = DEFAULT_PLAYER_WIDTH, height = DEFAULT_PLAYER_HEIGHT) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    };

    Player.prototype.draw = function () {
        game.fillStyle = "darkred";
        game.beginPath();
        game.moveTo(this.x - this.width / 2, this.y + this.height);
        game.lineTo(this.x, this.y);
        game.lineTo(this.x + this.width / 2, this.y + this.height);
        game.closePath();
        game.fill();
    };

    let player = new Player(canvas.width / 2);

    let draw = (millisecondsElapsed) => {
        game.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        fallers.forEach((faller) => {
            faller.draw();
            faller.move(millisecondsElapsed);
        });

        player.draw();

        // Remove fallers that have hit the ground. 
        fallers = fallers.filter((faller) => {
            return faller.y < canvas.height;
        });
    };

    // It is responsible for generating falling objects at random.
    const MIN_WIDTH = 10;
    const WIDTH_RANGE = 20;
    const MIN_HEIGHT = 10;
    const HEIGHT_RANGE = 20;
    const MILLISECONDS_BETWEEN_FALLERS = 800;

    let fallerGenerator;
    let startFallerGenerator = () => {
        fallerGenerator = setInterval(() => {

            let fallerWidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * WIDTH_RANGE) + MIN_WIDTH;
            fallers.push(new Faller(
                Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.width - fallerWidth)), 0,
                fallerWidth, Math.floor(Math.random() * HEIGHT_RANGE) + MIN_HEIGHT
            ));
        }, MILLISECONDS_BETWEEN_FALLERS);
    };

    let stopFallerGenerator = () => clearInterval(fallerGenerator);

    // This section is responsible for moving the "player" around based on mouse movement
    let setPlayerPositionBasedOnMouse = (event) => {
        player.x = event.clientX / document.body.clientWidth * canvas.width;
    };

    document.body.addEventListener("mouseenter", setPlayerPositionBasedOnMouse);
    document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", setPlayerPositionBasedOnMouse);

    let running = false;
    let nextFrame = (timestamp) => {
        if (!lastTimestamp) {
            lastTimestamp = timestamp;
        }

        if (timestamp - lastTimestamp < FRAME_DURATION) {
            if (running) {
                window.requestAnimationFrame(nextFrame);
            }

            return;
        }

        draw(timestamp - lastTimestamp);

        lastTimestamp = timestamp;
        if (running) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(nextFrame);
        }
    };

    document.getElementById("start-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
        running = true;
        lastTimestamp = 0;
        startFallerGenerator();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(nextFrame);
    });

    document.getElementById("stop-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
        stopFallerGenerator();
        running = false;
    });
})();
```

```css
canvas {
    border: solid 1px gray;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1024px;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Undefined</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="falling.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Not finished</h1>
    <p>
      <b>Score:</b> <span id="playerScore">0</span>
    <canvas id="game" width="1024" height="536">
      Sorry, but you need a web browser that supports the
      <code>canvas</code> element.
    </canvas>

    <p>
      <button id="start-button">Start</button>
      <button id="stop-button">Stop</button>
    </p>

    <script src="falling.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to implement collision detection, or use a library like Phaser to do that for you.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Ah, I need a collision detection. Thank you for giving me sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
isCollision = false
fallers.forEach((faller) => {
     isCollision = isCollision || checkCollision(faller,player) 
    });
if (isCollision) {
    //decide what you want to do here
    //maybe you want to display the gameOver screen and return
    //before drawing the fallers.
}
fallers.forEach((faller) => {
        faller.draw();
        faller.move(millisecondsElapsed);
    });
```

in your `checkCollision()` decide how accurate your collisions need to be. it may be that `absolute(player.x - faller.x) < delta` is accurate enough for you. if the fallers or player have width, you need to check if the players x interval overlaps with the players x interval. Also make sure you check the heights too.

Comment: What is this for? I already drew my falling objects with the correct speed.
fallers.forEach((faller) => {
        faller.draw();
        faller.move(millisecondsElapsed);
    });

Comment: in your draw() method, (event loop say), you filter fallers that have hit the ground. You should also check for fallers that have hit the player. So you need to insert code just above where you draw all the fallers, that code can check if any fallers have hit the player and decide what to do.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help!